# How to access to database objects in django custom save method?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, heroku

I have to check if the django model save method is for create new object or update it, because i have to update status of the child objects from parent if is updated.

```
class Categoria(Entidad):

  ESTADO = (("Activo", "Activo"), ("Inactivo", "Inactivo"))
  estado = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Estado"), max_length=20, choices=ESTADO, default=1)
  categoria_padre = models.ForeignKey('self', verbose_name=_("Categoría Padre"), related_name='parent_category', related_query_name='child_category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    from django.db import connection

    # first option does not work because i can access to django model manager
    old = self.objects.get(id=self.id)

    # second option throughs 500 error when create new objects
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    response = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM cms_categoria WHERE id = '" + str(self.id) + "'")
    set = response.fetchall()
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

The second options works on local development but not when push it to heroku with postgres.

Anybody could help me please ?
Thanks, Regards.

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simplify your `save()` method significantly, no need for importing connection and using cursors as far as I'm aware.

If in the save method you need to check if the instance already exists in the DB you can do something like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk:
        # update your child objects here if it has been updated
        pass
    return super.save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is because if the object is being created in the DB (i.e. new instance), it wont have a primary key assigned to it until `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` is called. If a primary key exists, you know it's being updated, not created.